# Converting dictionary string to dictionary failed

Tags: python

I tried to convert below string to dictionary by `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval` method but both failed, please kindly help:

```
text = '{"data":{"FormId":"BD_Rate","TopRowCount":0,"Limit":0,"StartRow":0,"FilterString":'',"OrderString":'',"FieldKeys":"FRateID,FDocumentStatus,FForbidStatus,FName,FDescription,FCreateOrgId,FUseOrgId,FCreatorId,FModifierId,FCreateDate,FModifyDate,FBegDate,FCyToID,FEndDate,FRATETYPEID,FCyForID,FAuditDate,FAuditorID,FForbidderID,FForbidDate,FIsSysPreset,FExchangeRate,FReverseExRate"}}'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the reason why you failed to convert is, your string include a single quote `'',`, meanwhile your string started with a single quote too. you can use `"""your string"""` to use long text.

Comment: Where did you get this string? `{"FilterString":''}` isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is quoted using single quotes (`'`) and you also have `"OrderString":''` as part of your string. Python will remove those `''` because it will assume string concatenation. For example:

```
s = 'foo''bar'
```

is equivalent to

```
s = 'foo' + 'bar'
```

hence the same thing as

```
s = 'foobar'
```

Change your first line to

```
text = '{"data":{"FormId":"BD_Rate","TopRowCount":0,"Limit":0,"StartRow":0,"FilterString":"","OrderString":"","FieldKeys":"FRateID,FDocumentStatus,FForbidStatus,FName,FDescription,FCreateOrgId,FUseOrgId,FCreatorId,FModifierId,FCreateDate,FModifyDate,FBegDate,FCyToID,FEndDate,FRATETYPEID,FCyForID,FAuditDate,FAuditorID,FForbidderID,FForbidDate,FIsSysPreset,FExchangeRate,FReverseExRate"}}'
```

and both `json` and `ast.literal_eval` will work.

Comment: It works, many thanks.